# How to Filter datas in excel to another worksheet?

Tags: excel

I have an Excel issue. Here is my worksheet:

```
| name       | price1 | price2 | price3 | pcs | selled |
| product 1  |    2.0 |    2.1 |    2.5 |   1 |      n |
| product 2  |   10.0 |   11.5 |   14.0 |   1 |      n |
| product 3  |   88.0 |   94.9 |   99.9 |   1 |      y |
| product 4  |  199.0 |  234.9 |  259.9 |   1 |      y |
```

Now I need to do a query (sorry, I use mysql basicly) what create a list based on this to an other worksheet what looks like this:

```
| name       | price1 | pcs | selled |
| product 1  |    2.0 |   1 |      n |
| product 2  |   10.0 |   1 |      n |
```

If I use MySQL I use this query:

```
SELECT name, price1, pcs, selled 
FROM tablename 
WHERE selled = 'n';
```

So, how can I do this in Microsoft Excel 2013? Important: I need to write datas to a new worksheet. If it is possible I need to do auto-update this query when the user update datas on the base sheet.

Is there any working example or tutorial for this?

Comment: is the `name` column unique?

Comment: no, not unique, but if there is need a required field we can create an ID field

Comment: use pivot table it will give you what you want.

Comment: pivot table generate me a summary isn't it? but I want only a filtered list without any summary... or if pivot can do it can you give me a link to a video or any tutorial what can explain how can I do this?